# is it possible to update an iOS app by XML files?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, cordova, audio-player

I am really new in app design, and do not know how can I add content to my app after is it out.  In my app I have music and video pages. I was thinking how can I add new music or videos to the app later ?! So it is possible to link the content to an xml file and keep the xml in a host. 
Therefor, to update add the app, I edit that xml file and when user loads the app it shows the XML contents? Is it actually how apps works? If this way works, or there are better ways to do it, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: If you mean to add extended features through, xml file is not possible. You need to Update the appstore build by adding a version to your project.

1) make changes to your project.
2) add a version in appStore for your app.
3) upload your latest binary to the store.

Comment: @Bharath Thanks for your post. No I don't mean adding new feature. Imagine there is an app that has a music player and plays music. How would you add new songs to the player?  Is XML the common way, or there is a better way? Another example can be a news app that everyday loads news.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question properly but if you want to update your xml content you can use the Kiss XML Parser.

Comment: Well, I think the title is clear. Is it possible to update the content of an app by a xml file ??

Comment: ya its possible. Just parse the xml file and what you meant by the app content exactly